# MySQL Search & Replace with WILDCARDS - Query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to perform a MySQL search and replace while honoring wildcards?

eg:

```
$search = "id='%wildcard%-houselisting-rental'>";
$replace = "class='house_rentals'>";
$query = "UPDATE tables SET field = replace(field,'$search','$replace')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I appreciate any advise on the subject 
-h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out this wasn't possible for mysql.

Comment: It's not easy, but it is possible. You have to use LOCATE and SUBSTR to pick out the parts you want to keep, and then CONCAT to join them together with the replacements. It's a horribly messy thing, but it's entirely doable. You could even wrap it up in a procedure.