# mySQL search and replace function with variables

Tags: mysql, replace

I've tried to solve this question on my own (I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630944/mysql-search-replace-with-wildcards-query) stackoverflow question), but I've hit a wall!

I'd like to make a "find & replace" mySQL query that converts html links in a record into a new format.  I thought the easiest way to do this would be to create a dictionary of terms to replace.  The problem is I don't know the syntax for the dictionary.  Here's the basic query idea:

```
    /*dictionary of terms to replace*/
    @dic = '/site1', '/site2,' '/site3,'

    /*create dictionary of replacement terms*/
    @rep = '/newsite1', '/newsite2', '/newsite3'

    UPDATE table_name 
    SET body = REPLACE(body, @dic, @replace)
    where content_id = 11;
```

Thanks for any guidance you can offer!

Comment: only /site1 will get the slash before newsite1? Or should it be /newsite2 and /newsite3 too?

Comment: @arnoudhgz that was just an accident.  /newsite1, /newsite2, etc are just stand-ins, I corrected it above.  There isn't a regex solution to this problem because the new links are fundamentally different URLS thank the old links.

Comment: @Dave, are there only 3 values to replace or is there an undefined number of replacements?

Comment: @HolgerBrandt, there is an undefined number of replacements, otherwise I'd just run three separate queries!

Comment: @Dave, unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a function that can do a multiple replace on an undetermined number of strings.

Comment: @HolgerBrandt. Bummer, that's what I'm starting to realize.  Thanks for the help!